# Halo 4: Lone Wolf Legend Achievement

Tags: halo-4

Im trying to get the `Lone Wolf Legend` achievement and it states: `Complete the campaign solo on Legendary difficulty.`

Which sounds simple enough (in terms of understanding the achievement requirements). When I look through the missions I have completed on legendary, the legendary symbol only appears in the co-op section and not in the solo section. I completed all missions so far ALONE and not with anybody else.

Can anyone tell me why the legendary symbol appears in the co-op symbol and not the solo symbol?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance you had a second controller connected?  Were you continuing missions that were partially completed in coop?

I'm posting the closest information I can related to your problem.  There is a known issue with completing stuff offline, but I see nothing of solo switching to coop.

From: https://forums.halowaypoint.com/yaf_postst130475_Issues-being-investigated.aspx

**Completed Campaign but missing achievements
Upon completing Campaign, some players find they are missing certain achievements. If you pause, you must use the "Resume Campaign" button to resume. If you choose "Rally Point Bravo" or "Rally Point Charlie", this issue arises. We are investigating but for now, replay the missions from beginning to end using only the “Save and Quit” and “Resume Campaign” options to unlock the relevant achievements.**